# How can a reuse an encrypted SSD?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

I bought a laptop on ebay that had a broken screen, didn't appear to have ever been opened before, and upon opening it, I found an SSD inside that I would like to format and use.

Gparted (and other programs including mkusb, and dd) report "Input/output error during read on /dev/sda".  If I click to ignore these about ten times, then I can see it in the drives selection pop down selection box as totally unallocated.  If I try to make a partition on the device, it says no partition table, create a partition table.  If I do that, it hangs.  I cannot write the first MB as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041688/how-can-i-format-an-encrypted-hard-drive-in-ubuntu) (r/w errors) either with mkusb or dd.

The drive is an Intel opal SSD with a PSID on the label, so I thought it was a self-encrypting-drive (SED), but using sedutil-cli --scan, the drive is reported as not SED.  When I try and boot up on the drive, it comes up with a lock and harddrive symbol and you can type a password.  It gives you three tries, and then a hand with a slash/circle through it pops up and you have to shutdown and try again.  It won't let you go to BIOS, or boot on another drive when it is connected to the SATA bus before booting.  The way I got the sedutil-cli to work was to make a USB drive from an [image from Drive Trust Alliance](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Executable-Distributions), then boot from it and put the Intel SSD in a USB enclosure, and connect it after booting from the image on a flash drive.

If I use the disk utility to check the SMART status, everything is fine.  I am certain this drive is encrypted, but I haven't been able to discover even what encryption it is, or any way to format it for reuse.

Can anyone give me any hints?  It seems such a waste to send this drive to the landfill, and buy a new one, just because I can't figure this out!

Thanks!

Here is some more data that might be useful:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
[sudo] password for frohro: 

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       INTEL SSDSC2BF180A4L                    
    Serial Number:      CVDA341204U11802GN  
    Firmware Revision:  LSTi    
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0xffff) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   351651888
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      171705 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      180045 MBytes (180 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 254
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
       *    Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
            Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
            unknown 78[10]
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    reserved 69[4]
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 16385
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level maximum
    4min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 55cd2e404b84ac1f
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 5cd2e4
    Unique ID   : 04b84ac1f
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 20 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 10 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: Brand and model of the SSD in question?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but have you tried ``blkdiscard --secure`` ?

Comment: It is an Intel.  See this photo of the drive data. https://photos.app.goo.gl/oLjqojhPWdWAAeEcA

Comment: It looks like blkdiscard is for telling the device you don't want to use those blocks anymore.  Do you have a suggested way to use that?  Do you think I should try and discard the first 512b block or something?

Comment: Maybe this is useful:

Comment: See the hdparm command output I did above.

Comment: Have you tried PSID reverting the drive like so: https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/PSID-Revert
I mean, this could be a dumb questions, but I could not find anything in your question about it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It has been over a year since I tried to use this drive.  I can't remember anymore if I tried this option.  I do remember looking on the drive for a number and finding it, but I don't remember if I tried this.  It does look promising.  I'll have to go find the drive and give it a try.  Again, thanks for the idea!