# Login not working after password change

Tags: encryption, password-recovery

I ran into the unfortunate scenario of forgetting my password on an old laptop running Ubuntu. I didn’t think much of it and changed the password using passwd, not realizing my home directory was encrypted. When I go to login screen, it just flashes. I don’t have the pass phase for the encryption although I am trying to find it. Is there anyway to either do a factory boot get around that problem?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve your lost encryption pass phrase.

Comment: You changed the password with `root` user?

Comment: Yes I changed password with root user. I found on a different post (after the fact) that if the home directory was encrypted, the only way to decrypt it to allow login would be to have that pass phrase. I don’t need to save any of the files on the hard drive but now need to figure out how to factory reset and boot new OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format an encrypted hard drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041688/how-can-i-format-an-encrypted-hard-drive-in-ubuntu)